# Parse python code for statis analysis

Tags: python, parsing

I'm thinking of writing some simple static code analysis that uses class declarations and comments to generate UML diagrams.

Can you suggest a comfortable way to parse Python scripts in a structured way? I will need to detect class declaration, module imports, parameter assignment in `__init__` and comments in a structured way.

Maybe you can point me to the specific sections I need? There is a large section on "Python Language Services" (parser, AST, ...), but I cannot make sense of which one I need and I'd like to avoid digging through all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use inspect to inspect the code after loading it:

http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Comment: This gives you knowledge about class structures and functions, possibly imports, but definitely not attribute assignment (from just the class/`__init__` code) and comments.

Comment: [ccbv](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/) uses inspect to show inherited methods i think it's worth to take a look at the [source](https://github.com/refreshoxford/django-cbv-inspector/blob/master/cbv/management/commands/populate_cbv.py)

Comment: Methods are fair game because they are part of the class. But how would you find instance attributes without instanciating an object? And comments are lost the second it's loaded from disk.

Comment: You can even receive single lines of code and comments. http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code

Comment: Oh, I keep forgetting that part of the API. Yes, this is a good idea, +1. A bit roundabout though if the module isn't already loaded. For many static analysis tasks, one needs the AST, or an even more detailed description (think control and data flow graphs).

Comment: Well, just source code lines I could get easier. For that I don't need inspect. What part of AST do I need to solve my task?